# Is it possible to search a file with comrpessed objects in java?

Tags: java, string, search, compression

I read from ORACLE of the following [bit:](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/serializationFAQ.jsp#compress)

> Can I execute methods on compressed versions of my objects, for example isempty(zip(serial(x)))?
>
> This is not really viable for arbitrary objects because of the encoding of objects. For a particular object (such as String) you can compare the resulting bit streams. The encoding is stable, in that every time the same object is encoded it is encoded to the same set of bits.

So I got this idea, say if I have a char array of 4M something long, is it possible for me to compress it to several hundreds of bytes using `GZIPOutputStream`, and then map the whole file into memory, and do random search on it by comparing bits? Say if I am looking for a char sequence of `"abcd"`, could I somehow get the bit sequence of compressed version of `"abcd"`, and then just search the file for it? Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the compression algorithm it could work, but the compression is not going to necessarily respect byte boundaries, so searching might really be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use GZIP or similar to do this as the encoding of each byte change as the stream is processed. i.e. the only way to determine what a byte means is to read all the bytes previous.

If you want to access the data randomly, you can break the String into smaller sections.  That way you only need to decompress a relative short section of data.